# Text View keeps resizing/resetting to zero size and coordinates

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

In my iOS application storyboard i have a few view controllers which contain one or more TextViews. Now, on almost everything i do within those views, like adding another button, or resizing a text box, those Text Views 'jump' back to the upper left corner and at the same time they get resized to 0,0.

Is this a bug, or can i do something about it?

I'm using Xcode 6.1

Comment: What constraints have you placed on the textviews?